# ScrollBot in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#myElement').css('top', $(this).scrollTop() + "px");
});
```

works great, but what if I want it fixed to the bottom instead of top?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you need to handle IE6? :)

Comment: Yes! :( Otherwise CSS would've done the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by adding the element's height to the `scrollTop` value:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var myElement = $('#myElement');
    myElement.css('top', $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() - myElement.height() + "px");
});
```

Alternatively, have you looked into using [position: fixed](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp)?  It works well in all browsers except IE, and you can get around it with [CSS expressions](http://annevankesteren.nl/test/examples/ie/position-fixed.html).

Comment: This would put the element off the screen :)  You need to subtract the element's height to have it back in the view port.

Comment: @Nick much obliged - example updated.  Out of curiosity, is it worth assigning `$('#myElement')` to a variable rather than doing the DOM lookup twice or are the jQuery lookups fast enough to make this a case of unnecessary optimization?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code & try out the demo : **http://jsbin.com/aguca3**

**HTML** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #scrollDown {
      color : #0099f9;
      border:5px solid #2f2f2f;
      background:#d5d5d5;
      -moz-border-radius:5px;
      -webkit-border-radius:5px;
      border-radius:5px;
      position:fixed;
      top:30px;
      right:30px;
      font:bold 14px Verdana;
      padding:5px;
      cursor:pointer;
    }
    #scrollDown:hover {
      color:#fcfcfc;
      background:#000;
      border-color:#0099f9;
    }




  </style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Change text</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="scrollDown" > Scroll Down </div>


<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> 

<span style="float:right;"> you have Reached the End of page</span>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript** :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#scrollDown').click(function() {
    var height = $('html,body').height();
    $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop: height},2000);
  });
});
```